# Phalcon Update Model does not work

Tags: mysql, database, model, phalcon

The problem is explained short with the following code. `$category->update()` results with true (or `$category->save()`) but really nothing happens.

```
$category = Category::findFirst('id=' . (int)$id);
if ($this->request->isPost()) {
    $category->setCategoryId($this->request->getPost('category_id', 'int'));
    $category->setLanguageId($this->request->getPost('language_id', 'int'));
    $category->setName($this->request->getPost('name', 'striptags'));
    $category->setDescription($this->request->getPost('description', 'striptags'));
    $category->setSort($this->request->getPost('sort'));
    $category->setValid($this->request->getPost('valid'));
    if (!$category->update()) {
        $this->flash->error($category->getMessages());
    } else {
        $this->flash->success(
            $this->translator->_('Category was updated successfully')
        );
    }
}
```

The model-classes are generated with getter- and setter-methods and protected member-variables with the phalcon-devtools.

What am I doing wrong?

I know this problem was also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346569/phalconphp-framework-how-to-update-a-model-object-and-the-related-object) but i unfortunately have not enough points to write a comment :)

**Phalcon Version 1.2.3, MySQL 5.5 + Apache on Debian with PHP5.4.4**

Comment: try printing the messages to a file: file_put_contents('a.txt', print_r($category->getMessages(), true));, then see: public/a.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be something as simple as a column that doesn't accept nulls and a null is being slipped in. If you don't explicitly tell Phalcon not to do so, even if you don't have any validation, Phalcon will enforce the not null constraint on the field implicitly.

Disable not null validations by adding this to the top of your bootstrap file and try again:

```
\Phalcon\Mvc\Model::setup([
    'notNullValidations' => false
]);
```

Comment: You're welcome. As a final note, remember that this won't stop MySQL from rejecting nulls in columns marked as not null. It will only stop Phalcon from doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Validation may be to blame? Check validators

Comment: There are no messages in `$category->getMessages()` even if I put it outside the if-condition. Second is I removed all validations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the php error log? I found that Phalcon is sometimes not as verbose as I would have liked it to be...

Comment: This log is quiet like a mouse. I can't figure it out.